# How to handle multiple clients and roles?

Tags: oauth-2.0, acl

I'm working on an OAuth 2.0 server to support multiple clients and roles.

Let's say I have an API server that requires an access token from an OAuth server.

These workflow I came up with. I have three serves for this simple workflow -- **OAuth**, **Client**, and **API server**.

1. Users on each clients have email and password (these credentials are stored on OAuth server)
2. Users sign-in with their email and password on their clients then the clients send the credentials to the OAuth server for authentication.
3. OAuth server checks the credentials and issue an access token.
4. When a user requests an request to an API server, API server talks to OAuth server to see if the user has access to the resource. If so, perform requested request then return something.

This is somewhat unusual workflow in my opinion. The reason I want to do this way is because we actually store user credentials on our OAuth server. I also have multiple roles (groups) for each clients.

Is this OKAY workaround or is there a better way for one OAuth + multiple clients and multiple roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is the equivalent of the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant in OAuth 2.0, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3. You should be able to do this with a stock OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server that supports this grant. So it is not unusual or proprietary but requires a great deal of trust in the client because it "sees" the password.

You can model multiple roles and groups by representing them as different "scopes" that are associated with access tokens and thus clients.

Comment: Thank you Hans Z. The problem I see is that the client app has to know or manage scopes on their end. For example, an admin user "test@test.com" tries to login, what scope should I request? In order to know what to request, client apps should be aware of user groups (or roles), but I really don't want to do that. I guess I can use user credential grant to issue access token then check scope when a user actually request something.

Comment: The client does not need to be aware of scopes, especially not in the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant. In any case you don't need to explicitly request scopes, you can also associate whatever scopes you want with the access token at the Authorization Server. The client then may not even know about scopes at all: it just gets an access token and uses it to success or failure, according to the underlying permissions/roles, typically a derived set of the Resource Owners permissions/roles.

Comment: Thank you Hans Z. I think that's the best way to handle it so far.